# rake error in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, rvm, rhodes

I was trying to do the following command but it shows the following error:

```
$ sudo rake dtach:install 
/home/uday/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ 
rubygems.rb:314:in `bin_path': can't find gem rake ([">= 0"]) with 
executable rake (Gem::GemNotFoundException) 
        from /usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Is there a way to get around this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs for RVM, the ONLY time you use sudo is for installation of RVM itself. The ONLY time you use rvmsudo once RVM is installed is for updating RVM itself. If you have used sudo at anytime other than the above described time, you will need to remove RVM and reinstall it. Trying to determine where permissions have been screwed up on the install itself is time consuming and error prone. Therefore, reinstallation is the better option.

You MUST add the users you wish to allow to use RVM directly on Multi-User installs to the rvm group and have th(at|ose) user(s) log out and then back in since group membership is only determined at login time.

Also, megas is correct. His command is the correct command to use per project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command: `bundle exec rake dtach:install`